# type alias `Point2` is private in Rust

Tags: rust, private, rust-cargo

I am following the tutorial on how to use GGEZ. I copied the showcase code.

```
pub use ggez::graphics::types::*;
pub use ggez::{graphics, Context, ContextBuilder, GameResult};
pub use ggez::graphics::{Image, DrawParam, Point2};
pub use ggez::event::{self, EventHandler};

fn main() {
    let (mut ctx, mut event_loop) = ContextBuilder::new(
        "Competition 8: gamedev", "Arkadiusz Bulski")
        .build().unwrap();
    let mut my_game = MyGame::new(&mut ctx);
    event::run(&mut ctx, &mut event_loop, &mut my_game);
}

struct MyGame {
    carimage: Image,
}

impl MyGame {

    pub fn new(ctx: &mut Context) -> MyGame {
        MyGame {
            carimage: Image::new(&mut ctx, "car_yellow_small_5.png").unwrap(),
        }
    }

}

impl EventHandler for MyGame {

    fn update(&mut self, _ctx: &mut Context) -> GameResult<()> {
        Ok(())
    }

    fn draw(&mut self, ctx: &mut Context) -> GameResult<()> {
        graphics::clear(ctx, graphics::WHITE);
        graphics::draw(&mut ctx, &self.carimage, 
            DrawParam::default().dest(Point2::new(512.0,128.0)));
        graphics::present(ctx);
        Ok(())
    }

}
```

Compiler told me to add a pub use to resolve the error. Now I got 2 errors. What do I do?

```
$ cargo build --release 
   Compiling source v0.1.0 (/home/arkadiusz/Dokumenty/competition-0008-gamedev/source)
error[E0603]: module `types` is private
  --> src/main.rs:2:25
   |
2  | pub use ggez::graphics::types::*;
   |                         ^^^^^ private module
   |
note: the module `types` is defined here
  --> /home/arkadiusz/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ggez-0.5.1/src/graphics/mod.rs:48:1
   |
48 | pub(crate) mod types;
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0603]: type alias `Point2` is private
  --> src/main.rs:4:44
   |
4  | pub use ggez::graphics::{Image, DrawParam, Point2};
   |                                            ^^^^^^ private type alias
   |
note: the type alias `Point2` is defined here
  --> /home/arkadiusz/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ggez-0.5.1/src/graphics/mod.rs:61:9
   |
61 | pub use crate::graphics::types::*;
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it kinda:

```
pub use ggez::{graphics, Context, ContextBuilder, GameResult};
pub use ggez::graphics::{Image, DrawParam};
pub use ggez::event::{self, EventHandler};
pub use mint::{Point2};
```